# NodeJs TCP client bufferSize to call multiple `data` event?

Tags: node.js, tcp

I just noticed that there is a `bufferSize` in NodeJs TCP Client which you can limit the incoming buffer to the TCP client.

So my question is that if I set the `bufferSize` in the client side to 1 byte and send 16 bytes from server, should I get 16 different `data` event in the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bufferSize` you're referring to is a [read-only property](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L361) of **writable** streams:

```
Object.defineProperty(Socket.prototype, 'bufferSize', {
  get: function() {
    if (this._handle) {
      return this._handle.writeQueueSize + this._writableState.length;
    }
  }
});
```

(correct me if you're talking about something else)

If you want to control how your client receives data, you should set your stream in [non-flowing mode](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable):

```
readable.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk;
  while (null !== (chunk = readable.read())) {
    console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);
  }
});
```

([see doc](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size))

You can pass `readable.read(5)` if you want to read just 5 bytes. The stream will be in non-flowing mode by default unless you attach a `'data'` event (so don't do it in your case).

Comment: thanks for the links, I think I was thinking wrong about the `bufferSize`. So I just have a small question, in non-flowing mode if I call `stream.read()` method, how much data should I receive?

Comment: stream.read() will return whatever data is available right now. If you pass an int, it will only return X bytes so you can parse data easily. If now data is available, you have to wait for the next `readable` event. I've edited my answer with parts of the node.js stream doc.

Comment: Many thanks for your response Laurent. Still I have some problems with the TCP packets, I mean for example is it possible to get two TCP packets at the same time from server or not? But I think I should ask it in different thread but if you have any resource/article about it, it should help me understand what's going on :)

Comment: When a TCP packet arrives, it goes in the socket buffer and trigger a `readable` event. Then, you can call `read()` to fetch all available data or `read(x)` to fetch just the first x bytes. However, node.js makes no guarantee that you will get packets one by one (you might get 2 at the same time if the event loop doesn't trigger your callback fast enough).